# Como guardar dados atualizados na base de dados

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, conexão

Eu estou a usar um dado da base de dados que diz o saldo do cliente antes do depósito e já tem o cálculo do depósito, mas eu agora quero guardar esse novo saldo atualizado na BD, é possível?

```
 decimal deposit = 0;
 Console.WriteLine("\n Quanto deseja depositar ?");
 deposit = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
 decimal value = depositarOperacao(debitCard, pin);
 decimal saldoAtual = value + deposit;
 Console.WriteLine(saldoAtual);
```

A minha dúvida agora é como guardar o saldo atual na base de dados, a coluna do saldo na base de dados é "Balance".

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: olá, essa pergunta está confusa, pergunta de banco de dados, tem ai um pedaço de código em c# que diz muito pouco, é preciso explicar melhor, só com isso  fica difícil de ajudar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ola, vai depender o banco de dados que esta usando, mas de modo geral se for um banco sql, basta usar o conector do banco por ex mariadb/mysql que usam o mesmo, eu uso o MysqlConnector para conectar em ambos. seguindo o basico seria mais ou menos assim:

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server = localhost; port=3306; user id = root; password = senha ");
conn.Open();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("update tabeladobancodedados set Balance = Balance + @saldoAtual",conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("saldoAtual", saldoAtual); //"saldoAtual" e o nome do parametro informado no update @saldoAtual podendo ser o que desejar, já o saldoAtual é a variavel do tipo decimal que ira pegar o valor a ser informado no lugar do parametro.
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: Obrigado já está funcional